# Installing CA cert file in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Im trying to install SSl on my nginx server. Everything works fine however Im receiving error while setting up my CA bundle file.
I dont know how to place my CA file in nginx.
For apache we place the cert files including CA file like this

```
SSLEngine on

 SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/example_com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example_com.ca-bundle
```

How would we place it in Nginx.
This is my config file for my nginx

```
server {
        root /var/www/html/example/dist;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name example.com;
server_name www.example.com;

  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /example/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3013/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com.crt;
   # ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/CAbundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
   # ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/CAbundle.crt;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam-2048.pem;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;


}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } 


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } }
```

Comment: See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate), but the server certificate and CA bundle need to be concatenated into a single file.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you ,it worked I missed this step $                                  
 cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt